# Understanding if application is launched by another application

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to detect if my application was launched normally or called by another application. Is there a way to understand it?

Comment: You can know if your activity was launched by another application/activity by checking if
`getIntent()` returns null in the activity you'd want to check. If it doesn't, then this was launched by another activity.

Comment: @PawanKumar that is not true. Calling `getIntent()` in an Activity will **always** return something non-null.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by 'launched normally'. Because another application could request a 'launch Intent' from the `PackageManager` and use that you launch your application and it would look just like this was launched by the user from the HOME screen. What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that when you are also the owner of parent application (the one where you start "your" application). I that case you could send some extra parameter in the Intent and read if it is there in your app. In don't think you can do that in any other case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Intent`s, `intent-filter`s and the data gathered from those.

For additional info look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html).